# How do you take the values of dropdown boxes and concatenate them into a single string of text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bunch of dropdown menus that a user can input some information from and I need to concat them and end with a string. I'm having issues with getting the data I need from the dropdowns to play nice, I keep getting an error saying that the value is null.

```
<select name="transType" id="transType">
  <option value="A">Create</option>
  <option value="B">Create and Transfer</option>
  <option value="C">Transfer</option>
  <option value="D">Receive</option>
  <option value="K">MW ID</option>
</select>
```

So Imagine I have a few different dropdowns like that

```
var type = document.getElementById(transType).options[transType.selectedIndex].text;
```

that code returns an error saying the value cannot be null. I'm probably making a dumb basic mistake. I'm pretty new to this. After I get that resolved though I would just make a new variable and concat to get my string right?

```
var allTogether = type+type1+type2...
```

Comment: yeah user select an option, and then concat all the options that they made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way ?

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.btConcat.onclick = e =>
  {
  let allTogether = Array.from(myForm.querySelectorAll('select'))
                    .map(sx=>sx.selectedOptions[0].textContent)
                    .join(' / ')
  console.clear( )
  console.log(  allTogether )
  }
```

```css
.as-console-row { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">

  <select name="transType" >
    <option value="A">Create</option>
    <option value="B">Create and Transfer</option>
    <option value="C">Transfer</option>
    <option value="D">Receive</option>
    <option value="K">MW ID</option>
  </select>

  <select name="transType2" >
    <option value="A2">Create2</option>
    <option value="B2">Create and Transfer2</option>
    <option value="C2">Transfer2</option>
    <option value="D2">Receive2</option>
    <option value="K2">MW ID2</option>
  </select>

  <select name="transType3" >
    <option value="A3">Create3</option>
    <option value="B3">Create and Transfer3</option>
    <option value="C3">Transfer3</option>
    <option value="D3">Receive3</option>
    <option value="K3">MW ID3</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" name='btConcat'> concat</button>
  
</form>
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll have to figure out why it isn't working in my jsfiddle later though. It makes the page 404 for some reason

Comment: @JustinBurnett I am open to any questions

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `options` property and use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert to an array, then map over each item to extract the `text` property and join together:

```js
var together = [...document.getElementById("transType").options].map(e => e.text).join('');
console.log(together)
```

```html
<select name="transType" id="transType">
  <option value="A">Create</option>
  <option value="B">Create and Transfer</option>
  <option value="C">Transfer</option>
  <option value="D">Receive</option>
  <option value="K">MW ID</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how do I tell what the user selected out of that? It just outputs all the options?